# Using second person plural with indirect objects

Tags: gramática, méxico, objetos-indirectos

What is used in Mexican Spanish instead of the “os” to form the second person plural with an indirect object?

Most sources online point to “os” but in many Spanish speaking countries this is not used.

I am living in Mexico and I don’t ever hear the “os” used. I have heard “los”, “las”, and “les” but wasn’t quite sure how to use them.

Comment: Hello and welcome to [spanish.se]! As is now, the question lacks some explanation on what did you investigate, what your hypotheses are, etc. Could you [edit] the post and show those, so we can assist you?

Answer (score 2):

Only in Spain do they use "os" for second-person-plural indirect objects (IO):

- **Os** ofrecemos un descuento. ("os" is the IO, while "un descuento" is the direct object.)

"os" can also be used as the direct object (DO):

- **Os** invitamos a participar.

In all other variants of Spanish, instead of "vosotros" the form "ustedes" is used, which is conjugated just like the third person plural "ellos". Therefore, "les" is used for IO and "los" or "las", depending on the gender, for DO:

- **Les** ofrecemos un descuento. (which, according to the context, can be interpreted as "We offer you(plural)/them a discount.")
- **Los/Las** invitamos a participar. (which, according to the context, can be interpreted as "We invite you(plural)/them to take part.")

Comment: It's correct, but add that "les" (& los, las) is the **ustedes** form. That's why it is like that.

Comment: You're right. I will.